# How many queries will fail if an error occurs within a single process of a single host?

Tags: autoscaling, server-crashes, crashlytics

Context:

I have a cluster of H hosts serving an API, where each hosts serves the api using P (constant) number of (python, but irrelevant) processes (asynchronously, but otherwise also irrelevant).

I have access to the following information (as graphs):

- the ageraged (per second) number of queries receiver over the whole cluster, R(t)
- The mean latency (time it takes to process a request) L=`L(t)`, which also varies with time.

  - mean is over seconds and across all process/hosts
- The number of hosts `H(t)`, which changes over time because of autoscaling.

An error can happen which kills a whole process and all in-process queries within, but the remaining processes keep working.

- The error rate (eg in #crashes per day per host) is known and constant, say `E`.

Problem:
I want to compute the (expected?) number of failing queries as a result of a crash.

Assumptions:

- the queries are equally balanced across hosts and processes.
- a failing process recovers "immediately"

Some thoughts:

- At any given second, the number of *new* queries should be `R(t) / [P*H(t)]`.
- This does not take into account the "running" queries not yet finished. I think I want to relate this somehow to L(t)...
- The inverse of number of new queries per second, `[P*H(t)] / R(t)`, should be smaller to `L(t)`, as otherwise it would mean its taking more time to complete a query than to receive a new one, eventually overloading the servers (which is not happening!)